# My Mac Mini won't go to sleep

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, screensaver

For some reason my mac mini refuses to start the screensaver or go to sleep unless I put the mouse into a hot corner. Energy saver is set to 3 mins as is system sleep. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  i have included a PMSET -G result but  don't really understand it. Many thanks. (Mac Mini, 2.5Ghz intel, 4GB RAM,  10.7.5)

```
AC Power        -1*
Currently in use:
hibernatemode   0
disksleep   10
womp        1
networkoversleep    0
sleep       5
powerbutton 1
ttyskeepawake   1
hibernatefile   /var/vm/sleepimage
autorestart 0
panicrestart    157680000
displaysleep    3 (imposed by 181)
```

Comment: could it be that your mouse sends a 'moving' signal to your machine? Have you unplugged your keyboard and mouse and tried to wait for 3 min?

Comment: Have you tried to use another user account?

Comment: What's a "hot corner"? (Literally a corner of the room that is hot?!)

Comment: @w3d In the system preferences, you can specify actions when the cursor enters any of the 4 screen corners. I have my display sleep/off when the cursor is in the lower left corner for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug this, you'll need to open terminal.app and look at the power assertions log. It's pretty verbose, but it really shows what's going on to prevent a sleep from happening.

```
pmset -g assertionslog
```

If you need a smaller set of data to look at, just ask for the current status and not an ongoing log of what's set and what's changing.

```
pmset -g assertions
```

You can close the window when you're done with the tools.

Comment: Thanks.  i did a pmset -g assertions and spotted this.     -------- Listed by owning process:  pid 181: [0x000000b5012c0009] PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep named: "extension" `code`-------- Any idea how  to got about deleting/editing this 'extension' what ever it is? Many thanks.

Comment: @joachim You could use Activity Monitor to look at that PID (process identifier number) - without knowing what it was and if it's still holding sleep 5 minutes later, it's hard to say what to do next. Be sure to show all processes in the monitor.

Comment: That all worked great. Discovered an extension that was keeing it awake. Thanks.